# Puppeteer is not clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to click a button on a login form with puppeteer. The form is actually rendered as a div and not a form. The the **OK** button that should be clicked to sign me in does not have an id or name or type. Just a class which is also used in about 3 other elements in the form. I have tried different methods to get it clicked, i either get an Error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')` or `Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement` or some other errors

```
<button class="input-button" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; width: 80px; left: 135px;">OK</button>
```

The different things i have tried

```
const [okBtn] = await page.$x("/html/body/div[15]/div/div[3]/button[2]");
  await okBtn.evaluate((b) => b.click());
```

```
  await page.click("/html/body/div[16]/div/div[3]/button[2]");
```

```
ait page.evaluate(() =>
    document
      .querySelector(
        "body > div.page-window.modal.login-form > div > div.b > button:nth-child(20)"
      )
      .click()
  );
```

```
const sub = await page.$$(
    "body > div.page-window.modal.login-form > div > div.b > button:nth-child(20)"
  );
  await sub[0].click();
```

What could i possibly be doing wrong or What am I missing?
This is my first time using puppeteer and I would appreciate some help or possible fix.

Comment: Use click event listeners or jquery click function

Comment: Without seeing the site, it's pretty hard to help. It could be in a shadow root, an iframe, loading after your click, etc...